# Mask RCNN model for Image segmentation is stuck on First epoch

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, image-segmentation, custom-training, mask-rcnn

I am dealing with issue where **my model is stuck on 1st epoch** (look below).
I am using this library which is the fork of the original Mask-RCNN library:

```
https://github.com/alsombra/Mask_RCNN-TF2
```

Dataset that I am currently using has `27 images` with **COCO-styled annotation** and `2 classes` excluding the background, which means that train and validation sets are accompanied with annotations.json (polygon marked points - coordinates and labels for each image in .json file).
I am using pretrained COCO model and train layers on top of that (`layers='heads'`). I am using Google colab to execute this.

The issue:

```
Starting at epoch 0. LR=0.001

Checkpoint Path: /content/gdrive/MyDrive/mask_rcnn/dataset/logs/marble_cfg_coco20230809T1836/mask_rcnn_marble_cfg_coco_{epoch:04d}.h5
Selecting layers to train
fpn_c5p5               (Conv2D)
fpn_c4p4               (Conv2D)
fpn_c3p3               (Conv2D)
fpn_c2p2               (Conv2D)
fpn_p5                 (Conv2D)
fpn_p2                 (Conv2D)
fpn_p3                 (Conv2D)
fpn_p4                 (Conv2D)
rpn_model              (Functional)
mrcnn_mask_conv1       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn1         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_conv2       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn2         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_conv1      (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_bn1        (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_conv3       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn3         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_conv2      (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_bn2        (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_conv4       (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_bn4         (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_bbox_fc          (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask_deconv      (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_class_logits     (TimeDistributed)
mrcnn_mask             (TimeDistributed)
Epoch 1/3
```

Execution path, debugger:

```
 <cell line: 6> -> navigate_next() -> train() -> navigate_next() -> train() -> navigate_next() -> ... -> model_iteration() -> navigate_next() -> get() -> get() -> wait() -> wait() -> wait()
```

Configuration:

```
Configurations:
BACKBONE                       resnet101
BACKBONE_STRIDES               [4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
BATCH_SIZE                     2
BBOX_STD_DEV                   [0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2]
COMPUTE_BACKBONE_SHAPE         None
DETECTION_MAX_INSTANCES        100
DETECTION_MIN_CONFIDENCE       0.7
DETECTION_NMS_THRESHOLD        0.3
FPN_CLASSIF_FC_LAYERS_SIZE     1024
GPU_COUNT                      1
GRADIENT_CLIP_NORM             5.0
IMAGES_PER_GPU                 2
IMAGE_CHANNEL_COUNT            3
IMAGE_MAX_DIM                  1024
IMAGE_META_SIZE                15
IMAGE_MIN_DIM                  800
IMAGE_MIN_SCALE                0
IMAGE_RESIZE_MODE              square
IMAGE_SHAPE                    [1024 1024    3]
LEARNING_MOMENTUM              0.9
LEARNING_RATE                  0.001
LOSS_WEIGHTS                   {'rpn_class_loss': 1.0, 'rpn_bbox_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_class_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_bbox_loss': 1.0, 'mrcnn_mask_loss': 1.0}
MASK_POOL_SIZE                 14
MASK_SHAPE                     [28, 28]
MAX_GT_INSTANCES               100
MEAN_PIXEL                     [123.7 116.8 103.9]
MINI_MASK_SHAPE                (56, 56)
NAME                           marble_cfg_coco
NUM_CLASSES                    3
POOL_SIZE                      7
POST_NMS_ROIS_INFERENCE        1000
POST_NMS_ROIS_TRAINING         2000
PRE_NMS_LIMIT                  6000
ROI_POSITIVE_RATIO             0.33
RPN_ANCHOR_RATIOS              [0.5, 1, 2]
RPN_ANCHOR_SCALES              (32, 64, 128, 256, 512)
RPN_ANCHOR_STRIDE              1
RPN_BBOX_STD_DEV               [0.1 0.1 0.2 0.2]
RPN_NMS_THRESHOLD              0.7
RPN_TRAIN_ANCHORS_PER_IMAGE    256
STEPS_PER_EPOCH                100
TOP_DOWN_PYRAMID_SIZE          256
TRAIN_BN                       False
TRAIN_ROIS_PER_IMAGE           200
USE_MINI_MASK                  True
USE_RPN_ROIS                   True
VALIDATION_STEPS               50
WEIGHT_DECAY                   0.0001
```

The model summary:

```
==================================================================================================
Total params: 65,833,892
Trainable params: 65,722,404
Non-trainable params: 111,488
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Hello, I am encountering the same issue, did you find a solution yet?